# How to handle/use special characters like percent (%) and ampersand (&) in Oracle SQL queries

Tags: sql, oracle, special-characters

I need to include the special character "%" in my LIKE clause in a SQL query, e.g.:

```
Select * From Some_Table Where Field_Name Like 'bla%bla&2';
```

How do I write that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to match Field_Name values that contain 'bla%bla&2', then you need to write this:

```
set define off
Select * From Some_Table Where Field_Name Like '%bla\%bla&2%' escape '\';
```

You get to specify which character you want to use to escape a following character (thanks should go to mathguy, not me). You also have to `set define off` to prevent sqlplus from trying to substitute values in a string.

If, however, you want to match Field_Name values that exactly equal the given string, then you do this instead:

```
set define off
Select * From Some_Table Where Field_Name = 'bla%bla&2';
```

Comment: Sorry, but no, that is not how you escape % in the LIKE condition. Best to delete this incorrect answer; someone already upvoted it, which means they think it is correct.

Comment: Sorry, but that means you don't know how to test, either. Try this: `select 1 as result from dual where 'yourstring' like 'your%%string';` According to you, the result set should have zero rows, because the input string doesn't have an ampersand in it. But in fact it does return a row with the value 1 in the `result` column.

Comment: @mathguy I posted the question and i voted for this answer. It worked.
I'm using Oracle SQL Developer. The ```set define off``` 
Why do you think it's wrong? state your reason. Thanks.

Comment: The ```set define off``` did help get around the "&", and the ```escape '\'``` skipped the "\".

Comment: @W.Elbashier - Under the Answer you will see a notation which is also a link, it says "Edited Aug 1 at 20:43". If you click on that link, you will see what was posted initially, then you will see how it was changed after I pointed out the original version wasn't going to work. As you can see in the edited answer, the responder specifically mentions that (which is the mark of a good responder - some people will make changes and pretend they didn't, as if we can't all see the history of changes through the Edited link).

Answer (score 4):

If I am not mistakend you escape them with a backslash (\)

```
Select * From Some_Table Where Field_Name Like 'bla\%bla&2' ESCAPE '\';
```

Comment: You need to add `ESCAPE '\'` after the `LIKE` condition to let Oracle know what you are doing. It's not automatic.

Comment: Added @mathguy's comment. I thought that was only when you needed to set a different char.

Answer (score 1):

Use escape \ to treat is a literal

```
SELECT *
  FROM Some_Table
 WHERE Field_Name LIKE 'blah\%'|| 'blah' ||'&'|| '2';
```

Comment: You need to add `ESCAPE '\'` after the `LIKE` condition to let Oracle know what you are doing. It's not automatic.

Comment: This may work for ampersand (I didn't test and I don't know off the top of my head if it will), but I do know it will not work for percent. The percent sign will be concatenated and then still interpreted as a meta-character in the LIKE condition. Escape is the right way, it just has to be done... the right way!

Comment: You are right for the percent and it has to use \ for it while for ampersand pipes can be used.

Answer (score -1):

I'll guess that you're using a tool which treats `&n`, where `n` is a digit, as a variable marker. If you're using SQL*Plus or SQL Developer you'd need to issue the SQL*Plus command `SET DEFINE OFF`. Other tools may use other methods to accomplish this.

Best of luck.

Comment: SQL\*Plus treats anything of the form `&z[...]` as a substitution variable - this is not limited only to digits. The solution is the right one though.

Answer (score -1):

I do not think the backslash escape character will work here for the ampersand.  Instead, you will want to divide your search into concatenated strings using double pipes.  Use single quotes around each piece of literal text.  Next, replace the & with  chr(38) which is the ampersand.  You can see this with:

```
select chr(38) from dual
```

You will still want to include the backslash before the % and finish your statement with escape '\'.  Notice, I did not quote the chr(38).

```
select * From Some_Table Where Field_Name Like 'bla\%bla'||chr(38)||'bla' escape '\'
```

Comment: This is correct and it will work, but the query is modified to work around an obstacle raised by the front-end program (like SQL\*Plus). The better solution, as Bob Jarvis has shown in his answer, is to tell the front-end to behave nicely - by turning off that feature in the front-end itself. We can't torture our queries so that they will avoid all the oddities of all possible front-ends; when we write a query we should only have to worry about SQL, not about other things. With that said, "good job" since the answer is actually correct.

Comment: I've never used set define off.  I'll have to add that one to my toolbox.

Comment: There is more to it. You can also set the marker for substitution variables to some other character (instead of &) - rather than turning that feature off. Each solution has its own uses/applications.